# What is the history of the incomplete "can"/"could" verb?

Tags: etymology, modal-verbs, historical-change, conjugation

The verb can/could is incomplete in the following sense.  There is a present tense:

- I can
- You can
- He/she/it can
- […]

There is also a past tense:

- I could
- You could
- He/she/it could
- […]

But there is no future, future perfect, imperfect or infinitive.  You have to use forms of “to be able” for that.

What is the history of this verb? Was it ever complete and did the other forms become archaic?  Is its incompleteness unique in English? Are there other English verbs with no infinitive for example?

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/can#:%7E:text=Old%20English%201st%20%26%203rd%20person,acquainted%2C%20try%2C%22%20Old%20Frisian) says

> Old English 1st & 3rd person singular present indicative of cunnan "to know," less commonly as an auxiliary, "to have power to, to be able," (also "to have carnal knowledge"), from Proto-Germanic *kunnjanan "to be mentally able, to have learned" (source also of Old Norse kenna "to become acquainted, try," Old Frisian kanna "to recognize, admit, know," German kennen "to know," Middle Dutch kennen "to know," Gothic kannjan "to make known"), from PIE root *gno- "to know."

Comment: You should include your research in the question so that others don't duplicate it.

Comment: @KillingTime Added an etymology. I can’t find any other useful information.

Comment: You're starting with the wrong information. _Can_ and _could_ are modal auxiliary verbs, and they are all defective -- no infinitive, no participles, no past tense, no present tense -- so they have very special syntax, as well as very special semantics. So is _will_, by the way; there's no future tense in English, just modals.

Comment: *cunning* is p.p. to *can*, sorta